# Why isn't this simple javascript code working?

Tags: javascript

The code is supposed to check whether the first few triangular numbers are prime (they are not), but it does not run.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>C1E9P1</title>
<script>

for(i = 3; i < 13; i++){
    prime = true;
    n = (i*(i+1))/2;
    for(i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n)+1; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    if(prime){
        document.write(n+" is prime.");
        document.write("<br>");
    } else {
        document.write(n+" is composite.");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}


</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is there an error message?

Comment: I try running it in my browser, but it only loads.

Comment: So are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Well once you figure out your issue, you are spitting out HTML in the head tag.

Comment: Not sure what you think `document.write` does...

Comment: Infinite loop I think, anyway, almost crashed my browser :) same iterating variable may not be a good idea

Comment: @epascarello How will this spit out HTML into the `head` tag?

Comment: @thomas Do you not see the script tag in the head?

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, but that's just going to append it to the document, not insert it into the head.

Comment: document.write writes where you are at...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used same variable for your two for loops that are nested!

```
for(i = 3; i < 13; i++){  <-- i
    for(i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n)+1; i++){ <-- i
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and look at your JavaScript console :

```js
for(var i = 3; i < 13; i++){
    var prime = true;
    var n = (i*(i+1))/2;
    for(var j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(n)+1; j++){
        if(n%j == 0){
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    if(prime){
        console.log(n+" is prime.");
        console.log("<br>");
    } else {
        console.log(n+" is composite.");
        console.log("<br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified script, but don't known if algorithm is correct.

```
for(var i = 3; i < 13; i++){
    var prime = true;
    var n = (i*(i+1))/2;
    for(var j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(n)+1; j++){
        if(n%j == 0){
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    if(prime){
        document.write(n+" is prime.");
        document.write("<br>");
    } else {
        document.write(n+" is composite.");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the inner for-loop's variable name to something else other than i.

```
for(i = 3; i < 13; i++){
  prime = true;
  n = (i*(i+1))/2;
  for(j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(n)+1; j++){
    if(n%j == 0){
        prime = false;
    }
}
```

You should be all good after that.